# How are the maximal ideals of a semisimple ring related to the ideals of the center of the ring?

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a semisimple ring, in the sense that the regular left module ${}_R R$ is semisimple. By the Wedderburn–Artin theorem I would expect there to be a bijection between the maximal (say left) ideals of $R$ and the maximal ideals of $\operatorname{Z}(R)$.

Is this correct? If so, is there a more direct way of obtaining this bijection without invoking Wedderburn–Artin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is in general no bijection between the maximal left ideals of $R$ and the maximal ideals of $\mathrm{Z}(R)$.

Let us consider the special case of $R = \mathrm{M}(n, )$, were $$ is some field.
The center is $R$ is $$, which contains precisely one maximal ideal.
But the ring $R$ contains at least $n$ maximal left ideals: we have for every column index $j = 1, \dotsc, n$ a maximal left ideal given by all those matrices whose $j$-th column consists of zeroes.
For $n ≥ 2$ we have no bijection between maximal left ideals of $R$ and maximal ideals of the center of $R$.

---

We do, however, have a bijection between the maximal two-sided ideals of $R$ and the ideals of $\mathrm{Z}(R)$.
This can be seen from the Artin–Wedderburn theorem thanks to the following facts:

- The maximal two-sided ideal in a product of rings $R × S$ are precisely of the form $I × J$ where $I$ is a two-sided ideal of $R$ and $J$ is a two-sided ideal of $S$.
- For every skew field $D$ and size $n ≥ 1$, the only two-sided ideal in the matrix ring $\mathrm{Mat}(n, D)$ are $0$ and $\mathrm{Mat}(n, D)$.
  In other words, $\mathrm{Mat}(n, D)$ is a *simple ring*.

---

I think this can also be established from the ground up as follows (sketch):

- The semisimple ring $R$ admits only finitely many simple modules $S_1, \dotsc, S_n$ up to isomorphism.
- For every $R$-module $M$, let $M_i$ be the $S_i$-isotypical component of $M$: the sum of all submodules of $M$ that are isomorphic to $S_i$.
  We have $M = M_1 ⊕ \dotsb ⊕ M_n$, a decomposition of $R$-modules.
  If $f \colon M \to N$ is a homomorphism of $R$-modules, then $f(M_i) ⊆ N_i$ for every $i = 1, \dotsc, n$.
- It follows that each $R_i$ is a two-sided ideal of $R$.
  The decomposition $R = R_1 ⊕ \dotsb ⊕ R_n$ is therefore one of two-sided ideals.
  It follows that each $R_i$ becomes a ring by restricting the multiplication of $R$ to $R_i$, and we then have $R ≅ R_1 × \dotsb × R_n$ as rings.
  (Each ring $R_i$ is again semisimple, with $S_i$ being it’s only simple module up to isomorphism.)
- It can be shown that each $R_i$ is simple. (This may require a technical lemma like one of the Jacobi density theorems; I don’t quite remember off the top of my head.)

We have thus found a decomposition $R = R_1 × \dotsb × R_n$ into simple rings.
(This is basically a weak version of the Artin–Wedderburn theorem.)

- It now follows that the maximal two-sided ideals of $R$ are precisely $R_1 ⊕ \dotsb ⊕ \widehat{R_i} ⊕ \dotsb ⊕ R_n$ for $i = 1, \dotsc n$.

So what about the center?

- We have $R ≅ \mathrm{Z}(R_1) × \dotsb × \mathrm{Z}(R_n)$.
- Every ring $T$ can be seen as a $T$-$T$-bimodule.
  The two-sided ideals of $T$ are precisely the sub-bimodules of $T$.
  Therefore:

  - $T$ is simple as a ring if and only if it is simple as a $T$-bimodule.
  - If $M$ is a simple $T$-bimodule then $\mathrm{End}_{\text{$T$-bimod}}(M)$ is a skew field by (a version of) Schur’s lemma.
  - The endomorphism ring of $T$ as a $T$-bimodule is precisely $\mathrm{Z}(T)$.

  We hence see that for a simple ring $T$, its center is a skew field.
- We see that $\mathrm{Z}(R_i)$ is a skew field for every $i = 1, \dotsc, n$.
- The maximal ideals of $\mathrm{Z}(R)$ are therefore precisely $\mathrm{Z}(R_1) × \dotsb × \widehat{\mathrm{Z}(R_i)} × \dotsb × \mathrm{Z}(R_n)$ for $i = 1, \dotsc, n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped clear up several things for me!